# What is the best way to transform a String to a list of different runtime types in Dart?

Tags: dart

What is the best way to transform a String into a list of different types in dart?  I currently have a String that looks like the following:

```
String exampleString = '[word, word 2, 5, 100, 5]'
```

I want to transform this into a List< dynamic> where the numbers are all of type int and any other fields, including 'word 2', remain as type String. I would like the result to look like this:

```
List<dynamic> finalList = ['word', 'word 2', 5, 100, 5]
```

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `dynamic` means a broad range of all possible types including both primitive types and custom-defined types. So, to convert them to all of the possible values, you have to write a method and know what types of values will be in the string. If you meant the word `dynamic` just to express [built-in types](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#built-in-types), here is how you can do that.

```dart
String exampleString = '[word, word 2, 5, false, 5.5]';

dynamic primitiveParse(String value) {
  // num for both int & doubles
  final asNum = num.tryParse(value);
  if (asNum != null) {
    return asNum;
  }

  // for bools
  final lowercase = value.toLowerCase();
  if (lowercase == 'true') {
    return true;
  } else if (lowercase == 'false') {
    return false;
  }

  // everything else as string
  return value;
}

void main() {
  final items = exampleString
      .substring(1, exampleString.length - 1)
      .split(',')
      .map((x) => x.trim())
      .map(primitiveParse)
      .toList();

  print(items);
  // -> [word, word 2, 5, false, 5.5]
  print(items.map((x) => x.runtimeType).toList());
  // -> [String, String, int, bool, double]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For conciseness, you can try:

```dart
// Remove the leading `[` and trailing `]`.
var content = exampleString.substring(1, exampleString.length - 1);
var finalList = <dynamic>[for (var p in content.split(', ')) int.tryParse(p) ?? p];
```